# Software to read a PDF aloud on Windows 10

Tags: pdf, windows-10, speech-synthesis

I've tried using Windows Narrator but I don't know how to make it read more than a single line of text at a time.  It seems to know the text continues since it will finish hyphenated words, but it just stops speaking after that unless I put the mouse over the next line of text, which results in a pretty disjointed reading experience.

I tried using Adobe Acrobat Reader but I couldn't get it to say anything at all with the Read This Page Aloud feature.  It just didn't do anything.  Seemed really janky and broken in general.

Comment: Is the text of your PDF selectable, or is it more like an image?

Comment: Obviously, or Windows Narrator wouldn't be able to read it.

Answer (score 3):

Most major PDF reader (like Acrobat and Foxit) should have reading aloud feature. If you still experience the same issue you might want to report bug to their developers. Or you can update to the latest version.

Comment: [Getting Acrobat Reader to work on Windows 10 seems like a pain.](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2252795)  I got Foxit to read the page, but I wish there were finer controls for this.  It repeats the title every time it's going to read a page, and it tries to read figures and shell code too, and there's no way to get it to start at an arbitrary place to avoid those figures.

Comment: So you want to request your wanted feature to them?